# Select rows that contain #N/A then paste them at the ending on page 2

Tags: vba, excel

I want rows that contain #N/A or #SAKNAS! to be added to the last row at page 2.

If there is no match, the code should just go on and not copy any empty rows.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="#SAKNAS!"

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Find(What:="#N/A", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)

rng.Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Latest masterlist").Select
Dim LASTROW2 As Long
LASTROW2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Rows(LASTROW2).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

If the code does not find "#N/A" I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using #NA and #Saknas as your criteria use

```
AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>#N/A", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>#SAKNAS!".
```

And delete these rows to get the desired rows containing `#NA and #Saknas`

One more way to do it is to insert two dummy rows in your sheet on with #NA entry and one with #saknas entry. rest of the columns wont matter, what this will do is it won't create error even if there were no #NA row present.